# Equality of two trigonometric integrals on [0,1]

Tags: improper-integrals

I need to show, that :

> $$\int_0^1 \cos(x^2)~\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1  \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt x}~\mathrm{d}x$$

But frankly I cannot see way to solve it. The right-side integral is improper and as far I know both of them don't have the elementary antiderivatives.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What substitution could you try to transform the left into something that looks like the right?

Comment: I think what might be making this confusing is the use of $x$ on both sides. Try changing $x$ to $t$ on one side and then try Daniel Fischer's suggestion.

Comment: For those interested, this is a [Fresnel integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $t=x^2$. Then $x=\sqrt{t}$. $dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}dt$

Then change the bounds: if x=0, t=0, if x=1, t=1. So the two integrals are equal. The name of the variable does not chage the things.

Comment: I think statement such as "$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(t)dt$ are equal" should be more appropriate.

Comment: You are right. Your statement is more clear. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! It was very clear. Is there any difference when we change limits from [0,1] to [0,+inf]?

Comment: The limits are as I wrote. If you change $t=1/x$ and $x \in [0,1]$ then $ t \in [1,\infty)$.